# Permission for Standard button?

Tags: permissions, button, page-layout

This should be simple, but I can't find this particular permission. A user's profile is set to be able to Edit Contacts (on the record type in this issue - that's fine), but when they click "Edit" in Contact Details, they get a page saying they have insufficient privileges.

I went to their layout, and none of the fields are locked except one, but there's no setting I can see for this button in particular - how can I remedy this?

Contact is Private in OWD, but I as an admin can edit it, and I thought permission sets/profiles would allow access if specified. What do I need to do?

Comment: Is the user has Read/Write access to that record? This is not about Edit permission to the profile, it is about Edit access to the record

Comment: Read, Create, Edit, and Delete, yep! Is this what you mean?

Comment: I actually don't think I follow - I'm in their profile, which has Read, Create, Edit, and Delete. Where should I be looking?

Comment: Is that record is shared to the user who is editing the record? Check the OWD of the Contact and any sharing rule exists through which record is shared to the user

Comment: I'm sorry, can you more explicitly direct me where to go? I'm more natively a developer and I'm still learning admin things and I'm not sure what OWD is. To my understanding, this is editing a record, and that depends on their Profile. Can you explain what I need to do exactly?

Comment: Not sure what Sharing has to do with it

Comment: Oh - OrgWide Defaults? It's Private...but I, admin, am able to Edit with this button

Comment: If the sharing is Private for the object, then the user's Profile/PermSet permissions of Edit/Delete (and field access) only apply to records to which they have sharing access to. In a standard Private sharing model, that would be records they own directly, or which are owned by users below them in the Role Hierarchy. They clearly have Read access to the record through the Sharing model, though.